# problems on google colab pytorch learning-RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error

I'm very newbie on pytorch and deep learning, and I got some error while running a sample code from deep learning class.

When I run the code I attached below, There comes an errors like,

```
text = torch.from_numpy(data['text']).long().cuda(0)

# feature extraction
mel_gt = get_mel(audio)

# shift mel spectrogram -> the input of the network
mel_shift = torch.cat((torch.zeros_like(mel_gt)[:,:,:1], mel_gt[:,:,:-1]) ,axis=-1)

# inference
mel_est, attention = model(mel_shift, text)
```

**RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!**

I can hardly understand because I also check whether the tensors are on cuba with these code, they all return true..

```
print(mel_shift.is_cuda)    
print(mel_gt.is_cuda)
print(text.is_cuda)
```

Can you guys figure out what's the problem?? I need big big help,,

Comment: did you do "model.cuda()"?

Comment: yes i did , before I start training.

Comment: show us your model, and the exact line that you wrote that throws the error inside your model class

Answer (score 1):

Check if your model is loaded on cuda by running
`next(model.parameters()).is_cuda`.
If it returns `False`, load the model on CUDA using

```
device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
model.to(device)
```