# Pytorch error- device : expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices

Tags: pytorch

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091226/runtimeerror-expected-all-tensors-to-be-on-the-same-device-but-found-at-least) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70736440/problems-on-google-colab-pytorch-learning-runtimeerror-expected-all-tensors-to) too. But the error persists.

I'm trying a simple feedforward NN using pytorch (from a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c36lUUr864M&t=10674s)).

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transformers

# hyperparameters
input_size = 784
hidden_size = 100
num_classes = 10
num_epochs = 2
learning_rate = 0.001
batch_size = 100

# activating device
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# Loading data
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('.', train=True, transform=transformers.ToTensor(), download=True)
test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('.', train=False, transform=transformers.ToTensor(), download=False)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)


class FeedforwardNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(FeedforwardNN, self).__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.r1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.l1(x)
        out = self.r1(out)
        out = self.l2(out)
        return out


model = FeedforwardNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_classes)
model.to(device)  # Added to solve the mentioned error, but to no avail.

# Loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)


# Training Loop
n_total_steps = len(train_loader)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        images = images.reshape(-1, 28*28).to(device)
        y_pred = model(images)
        loss = criterion(y_pred, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
```

I get the following error

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument target in method wrapper_nll_loss_forward)
```

I tried adding `to(device)` on `criterion` and `optimizer`. But that doesn't resolve the error.

The tutorial that uses the same code seems to run properly.

At the time of this writing `cuda` is inactive. Although that shouldn't matter as we had given an `if` condition, that will then choose `cpu`

```
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

Where should be the error then ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to move the `labels` to the device in the loop,